# Why is NodeJS not calling finish event with stream?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, node-streams

I have a series from streams. First is readable stream that reads from `AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>`, the second is a `Duplex` stream that resizes image and the third is a `PassThrough` stream whose only role is to send data from one end to the other. After that, I want to upload the file to an S3 storage.

The code looks roughly like this

```
import * as stream from "node:stream/promises"
await stream.pipeline(
  Readable.from(data) // Data are AsyncIterable,
  this.scaler.scale() // This returns the Duplex stream which resizes the image
  this.storage.createUploadStream() // This returns the PassThrough stream
)
```

The implementation of `this.storage.createUploadStream()` looks like this

```
const passThrough = new PassThrough();

const splitPath = attachment.storePath.split("/");
splitPath[splitPath.length - 1] = generateSafeS3Filename(splitPath[splitPath.length - 1]!);

const s3SafeKey = splitPath.join("/");

const uploader = new Upload({
  client: this.s3Client,
  params: {
    Bucket: this.config.bucket,
    Key: s3SafeKey,
    ContentType: attachment.contentType,
    Body: passThrough,
  },
});

passThrough.on('finish', async () => {
  await uploader.done();
})

return passThrough;
```

From what I understand from my code, it should pipe the data all the way to the `PassThrough`. Then I listen to `finish` (Writable) event to know when the data are written. Only then I want to call `uploader.done()` so that the class `Upload` from `@aws-sdk/lib-storage` knows that all data are available and can be uploaded accordingly.

The problem is that no `finish` event is ever called. It just hangs. I have tried all possible combinations. I even tried listening to event from the piped stream from `scaler` like this

```
passThrough.on("pipe", (source) => {
  source
    .on("finish", async () => {
      await uploader.done();
    });
});
```

In this case, finish is called prematurely and the whole process ends before any file is uploaded to S3.

What's interesting is that if I use simple `createReadableStream` instead of `PassThrough` stream like this

```
import * as stream from "node:stream/promises"
await stream.pipeline(
  Readable.from(data) // Data are AsyncIterable,
  this.scaler.scale() // This returns the Duplex stream which resizes the image
  createWriteStream('path')
)
```

it works normally, it writes the file to my filesystem and it ends. There's some magic hapenning I don't understand